# How can i resolve a problem with Logstash?

Tags: logstash

I have installed java: jdk11 and jre11 , also logstash installed via apt-get, but when i call it: `systemctl enable logstash`
Here is answer:

```
Failed to enable unit: Unit file logstash.service does not exist.
```

So when i type `apt-get install logstash`
system says that it has already installed.

Comment: Maybe check over on Unix & Linux SE?

Comment: May be you are right, i use parrotOS

Comment: So what i should to do?

Comment: I tried to use chmod 777 but system just can't see logstash despite it installed. System says that such file doesn't exist

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *insecure.*** You should revert to sane permissions ASAP, or, in the worst case, if you have a public-facing system with insecure permissions, reinstall it from scratch.

Comment: @MickeyU telling us what you did is great, but it should be part of the question as an [edit].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following steps to create the `logstash.service` file.

1. Edit the file `/etc/logstash/startup.options` and put the variables for your `java` binary and `java home`, something like that:

```
JAVACMD=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/java
JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_161
```

2. Run the script `/usr/share/logstash/bin/system-install`

After running the `system-install` script you should be able to start logstash as a service on your system.